# Accessing array objects in PHP sent from an iPhone app

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json, post

I have an iPhone app that makes a post request with an NSData object that in the form of JSON (code below for reference). I am sending GPS coordinates from CLLocation but would like to access the individual elements in PHP so I can store them in some db (will do that later).

From some reason I can not find a way to access the individual fields in PHP and I either get the entire array or nothing.

Objective-C code for reference:

```
  NSDictionary *locationDic = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
      [NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.coordinate.latitude], @"lat",
      [NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.coordinate.longitude], @"long",
      [NSNumber numberWithDouble:location.speed], @"speed",
                       nil];


  NSError *error;
  NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:locationDic
      options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted // Pass 0 if you don't care about the readability of the generated string
      error:&error];

  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/location.php"]];
  [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  [request addValue:@"postValues" forHTTPHeaderField:@"HTTP_METHOD"];
  [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
  [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];    
  [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
```

PHP:

```
$handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
$http_raw_post_data = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
    $http_raw_post_data .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);

$post_data = json_decode($http_raw_post_data,true);

if (is_array($post_data))
{
    $response = array("status" => "ok", "code" => 0, "original request" => $post_data);
}
else
{
    $response = array("status" => "error", "code" => -1, "original_request" => $post_data);
}

$processed = json_encode($response);

echo $processed;
echo $processed[0];
```

Any idea what I may be missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I get the payload more simply than you are :

```
  $content = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $ary = json_decode($content , true);
```

and get an associative array whenever the JSON is well formed.

Comment: Thanks, this is cleaner. Does not help me with my question though...:( stuck unable to parse the array....

Comment: @moshikafya can you add an echo of $http_raw_post_data in the body of the question ?

Comment: I am using your code so don't have 'http_raw_post_data' anymore :)